# 2 Sistemas de rutas independientes con react-router

Tags: reactjs

lo que quiero hacer es que mí pagina web tenga panel de administrador con la siguiente rutas /admin/.... y luego la web normal seria /...

Pero las url se me juntan cuando entro en / funciona bien pero cuando entro en /admin se ve el menú de la web y el menú del administrador cuando solo se tendría que ver el menú del administrador dejo el demo que realizado en CodeSandBox, espero que me podáis ayudar.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-admin-users-5wzte

Un saludo y gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí te muestro mi solución a tu problema planteado con `react` y `react-router-dom`. Tome tu código y lo modifique un poco.

JS:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function RouteWithSubRoutes(route) {
  return (
    <Route
      path={route.path}
      exact={route.exact}
      render={props => (
        // pass the sub-routes down to keep nesting
        <route.component {...props} routes={route.routes} />
      )}
    />
  );
}

function Layout({ routes }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {routes.map((route, i) => (
        <RouteWithSubRoutes key={i} {...route} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

function Home() {
  return <h1>Home...</h1>;
}

function Contact() {
  return <h1>Contact...</h1>;
}

function Admin({ routes }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {routes.map((route, i) => (
        <RouteWithSubRoutes key={i} {...route} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

function AdminHome() {
  return <h1>Admin Home...</h1>;
}

function AdminUsers() {
  return <h1>Users Admin...</h1>;
}

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/admin",
    component: Admin,
    exact: false,
    routes: [
      {
        path: "/admin",
        component: AdminHome,
        exact: true
      },
      {
        path: "/admin/users",
        component: AdminUsers
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: "/",
    component: Layout,
    exact: false,
    routes: [
      {
        path: "/",
        component: Home,
        exact: true
      },
      {
        path: "/contact",
        component: Contact
      }
    ]
  }
];

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/admin">Admin</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <Switch>
        {routes.map((route, i) => (
          <RouteWithSubRoutes key={i} {...route} />
        ))}
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[Aquí te adjunto el codigo fuento.](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-admin-users-1d53o?fontsize=14)  ¡Suerte!.

Comment: Es lo que necesitaba, gracias crack!